# How can I conserve a fraction as a part of the numerator?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I am doing some symbolic processing in Mathematica.

I end up with something like

```
Expr1 = a/b
Expr2 = c + d + f
```

Then I want to evaluate Expr1/Expr2, but I want to keep the fraction in the numerator. Basically, I want my final expression to be

$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c+d+f}$$

However, Mathematica insists on doing this

$$\frac{a}{b(c+d+f)}$$

which would not be problematic if later I did not need to evaluate the denominator of this expressions and getting $b(c+d+f)$ instead of $c+d+f$. Is there a way of fixing this?

Comment: This looks like one of those things Mathematica does automatically. Any trick you will do to prevent this will not work when you want to evaluate the whole expression later one. For now, you can do this: `e1=HoldForm[a/b];
e2=c+d+f;
res=e1/e2;
Denominator[res]` which gives the denominator you wanted. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY3i8.png)  but the problem with this solution is that `res` now has `HoldForm` inside it. Once you release this, the expression will go back to what it wants to be. i.e. `ReleaseHold[res]` will give what you showed.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to avoid assignments all together and use replacements. This was you do not have to use HoldForm as in the comment above.  As mentioned in comment, this is one of those automatic simplification that Mathematica does and it is very hard to prevent these without doing tricks such as HoldForm or modify the $Post and so on.

Instead of assignments, you can use replacements this way you can control everything.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
res = e1/e2
parm = {e1 -> a/b, e2 -> c + d + f};
```

Now you can do

```
Denominator[res] /. parm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Numerator[res] /. parm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To find the whole `res`

```
res /. parm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
expr1 = a/b;
expr2 = c + d + f;

expr3 = HoldForm[Evaluate@expr1]/expr2
```

[image]

```
Numerator[expr3]
```

[image]

```
Denominator[expr3]

(* c + d + f *)
```